# What's the difference between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}_3$?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

My course problem booklet (mathematics BSc, second year module in algebra, unpublished) uses them in a context which suggests $\mathbb{R}_3$ might be the same as M$_{1,3}(\mathbb{R})$. I'm used to the idea that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the home of elements which in some sense contain 3 elements from $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure exactly what distinction is being made by the subscript vs. superscript.

The subscript expression occurs in part (f) of the question shown below.

**Screenshot of question:**
[image]

Comment: I guess one denotes the row vectors and the other column vectors.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but the same question locates "the linear function $ax+by+cz$" in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which suggests your answer may not be the whole picture.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the notes? It's difficult guessing what is meant without having the booklet. I must say, the phrase "the linear function $ax+by+cz$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$" is vague. Do they mean a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)\mapsto ax+by+cz$? I wouldn't call this a function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but rather a function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Done. Also just realised I forgot to tag you in my last comment.

Comment: Okay, the only appearance of $\mathbb{R}_3$ is in question $f$. First of all, the linear function in question is $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)\mapsto ax+by+cz$ and they say it's a function **on** $\mathbb{R}^3$, this means that it's defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or equivalently, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's also somewhat unusual that they write $[a,b,c]\in \mathbb{R}_3$ (typically when we denotes elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we use round brackets). My guess is that they use $\mathbb{R}_3$ to somehow talk about a "parameter space".

Comment: To make sense out of the question, you can simply interpret $\mathbb{R}_3$ as $\mathbb{R}^3$. It doesn't change the question.

Comment: I take your point about the in/on distinction, and that interpreting $\mathbb{R}_3$ as $\mathbb{R}^3$ seems reasonable. I was wondering if there's a standard distinction between the two notations, and judging from your answer I gather there may not be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Keep your eyes open for other instances of this usage. Based on this question, I don't really think it's important. I think the author reserves $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the vector space and uses $(x,y,z)$ as the notation of an element of a vector space and uses $\mathbb{R}_3$ for parameter spaces and $[a,b,c]$ as the notation for a point in the parameter space. There is a slight distinction in the sense that you don't expect to able to do operations on points in parameter spaces (the addition of two such points holds little meaning as it's most likely not a point of interest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Mathematician 42's first comment is the correct answer. I will try to elaborate on it.

First, let $$f = ax + by + cz$$
Observe that we can write
$$f = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} \tag{*}$$
Here we use $(\cdot)$ instead of $[\cdot]$ for row vectors but this is only a matter of convention. I think $(*)$ is the reason why the author used row vector for $a, b, c$ but column vector for $x, y, z$. This is very natural once you take matrix multiplication into consideration.

Now if we set $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_0 & b_0 & c_0 \end{pmatrix}$$ We immediately see that
$$f|_{\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_0 & b_0 & c_0 \end{pmatrix}}$$ is a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ because it maps $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a_0 x + b_0 y + c_0 z$$
This is why the author said "the linear function $ax + by + cz$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$" in part (f).

To sum up,
$$\mathbb{R}^3 = \mathbb{R}_{3,1} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w\end{pmatrix} \middle| u, v, w \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
and
$$\mathbb{R}_3 = \mathbb{R}_{1,3} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} u & v & w\end{pmatrix} \middle| u, v, w \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Any answer will be somewhat speculative because we do not get the *definitions* of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R_3$. Your problem booklet certainly refers to some text and I guess you will find all definitions therein. Anyway, your screenshot suggests that an obvious distinction between $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R_3$ is this: Elements of $\mathbb R^3$ are written as *column vectors*, elements of $\mathbb R_3$ as *row vectors*. Column vectors are nothing else than $(3 \times 1)$-matrices, row vectors are $(1  \times 3)$-matrices. You may regard this a mere notational issue, and in fact for the purpose of the exercise it does not play an essential role. However written, the vector $[a,b,c]$  is only used to define the linear function $\lambda(x,y,z)  =ax + by + cz$.

But recall that each linear maps $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ can be represented by a $(m \times n)$-matrix $A$. Then we get $f(x) =  A \cdot x$, where $x$ and $f(x)$ are written as column vectors and $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication. Using this identification of linear maps and matrices, we see that the row vector $[a,b ,c]$ can be regarded as a linear map $\lambda : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$. This gives a *different interpretation* of row vectors and column vectors although both are described by three real parameters.

For a more detailed discussion you can have a look at [Is there a reason vectors in space are represented as column vectors (in that nothing works with row vectors)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3041616)